# View and Insert into Xref table with Entity Framework?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, .net-3.5

I have 3 tables, but when I create my edmx, it only shows 2 on the edmx model.  I also can't access my xref table through navigation.  I need to insert the primary key id from each table into the xref table, but I have no idea how to do it since I am not getting any navigation properties and it does not show up in the model.  Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Message (
  id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email_body TEXT BINARY NOT NULL,
  create_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


CREATE TABLE Address (
  id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMEN
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE AddressMessageXref (
  message_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  address_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (message_id, address_id),
  INDEX address_id (address_id),
  INDEX message_id (message_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_AddressMessageXref_Address_id FOREIGN KEY (address_id)
    REFERENCES Address(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT FK_AddressMessageXref_Message_id FOREIGN KEY (message_id)
    REFERENCES Message(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
```

What I need to do is after I Insert into the Message table and Address table, I need to insert the returned id's into the AddressMessageXref table.

Answer (score 1):

The Xref table is not visible from EntityFramwork, the framework will fill it for you.

```
public class Message 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Body {get;set;}
    [...]
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses {get;set;}
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [...]
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages {get;set;}
}
```

Using a setup like this one, when you will be adding a Message to an Address or vice-versa. EntityFramework will actually in inserting data into your Xref table.

Example:

```
var address = new Address();
var message1 = new Message();
var message2 = new Message();
message1.Addresses.Add(address);
address.Messages.Add(message2);

dataContext.Addresses.Add(address);
dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

That code would insert 1 entity in the address table, 2 in the message table and 3 in the Xref table.

Comment: I kept re-adding the entities like 3 times thinking it is somehow missing my third table before I read this post.. thanks!

Comment: I wasn't seeing the XREF table created either but then I noticed there was an error in the EDMX file saying I don't have a primary key specified in the XREF table.. I added that and now the third table shows up.